# Why can I import libraries that are not in my virtual environment in python Jupyter NN?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I have created an empty virtual environment in python3 . When I run `pip list`, it shows that I have nothing or almost, as you can see below:

[image]

When, I open a jupyter notebook, I see that I can use this environment:

[image]

But when I run an `import pandas as pd` it works, while `pandas` is not in my environment.

Do you have an idea of what is going on?

Thank you.

Comment: What method did you use to install Jupyter? Could you also mention what operating system you're using?

Comment: I went on their website and run the downloaded .exe. I am on mac

Comment: @Jensun I tag you in case you were not notified by the previous message